# Validate if email address exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to check whether my email address has valid host, exist for example someone@yahoo.com might return valid meanwhile some@yahozzz.com might return invalid (because invalid host)

I stumbled upon a code in git for golang that satisfy my needs for that https://github.com/badoux/checkmail, but currently at the moment i'm looking for the solution in javascipt, any help will be appreciated.

P.S. : I am using this code as a script inside my HTML

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use regex?

Comment: you should definitly use regex. if this is some kind of homework you should think about this yourself.

Comment: no no, what i am trying to figure out is not format checking for the email but rather to check whether the email really exist or valid (some@yahoo.com is valid while some@yahozzzo.com might return invalid), i edited my answer so it will become more clear

Comment: You need to determine if an MX record exists in DNS for the hostname, which means you need to make a DNS query, but JavaScript has no built-in mechanisms for I/O and depends on the host environment to provide such APIs … and you haven't said what host environment you are using. Node.js? WSH? An HTML document loaded in a browser? A browser extension? etc.

Comment: I have added the environment for it, thanks @Quentin

Answer (score 1):

Actually to verify that an email **exists and is active** you have to send a message to the email server and check the response.
That cannot be done entirely in javascript although you can rely on a service instead than on your backend like [this](https://verify-email.org/)

Comment: If this should be done programatically, where should I start? Any pointers?

Comment: Take a look at my link, there are a lot of services for email check

Comment: I'm not planning to use a service but to create one. I think i can verify whether the domain exists but how to verify mailbox is there or not?